# concurrency in Java - just on a method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've read some tutorials online and finding it hard to follow and they all refer to setting up a  new  class and running the threads on the main. I don't have a main as I'm building a backend for a GUI and I am just working to an interface.

I have pasted a sample of code below, to try and demonstrate what I want do.

```
public class TestClass {

public void testMethod(){
    Queue<List<Long>> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
    List<Long> testList = new ArrayList<>();
    testList.add(9L);
    q.add(testList);

    while(q.size()>0){
        //take off list from front of queue
        //manipulate list and return it to queue/Delete it if no more to add and not reached a threshold.
    }
```

So basically I'd like to call the while loop as a thread as I want to be able to control the time it runs for and also get some efficiency.

Can someone advise please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `while` loop to something like this.

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        while (q.size() > 0) {
            // take off list from front of queue
            // manipulate list and return it to queue/Delete it if no more to
            // add and not reached a threshold.
        }
        //all other code
    };
};
t.start();
```

Or you can wait for the thread to finish execution but that again blocks your testMethod until your while loop finishes. I don't think this is what you need.

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        while (q.size() > 0) {
            // take off list from front of queue
            // manipulate list and return it to queue/Delete it if no more to
            // add and not reached a threshold.
        }
    };
};
t.start();
t.join();//waits for the thread to finish execution.
//rest of your code.
```

Comment: That is allowing my code to run @Johnson Charles however, there is code after the while statement, which I didn't want running prior to the while statement being exhausted. Any ideas?

Comment: You can move everything after while to the run method of the thread, but it depends on your need. If you want to execute it only after thread finishes its execution then see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that works. Any idea how to limit to to run for a certain number of seconds please?

Comment: You have to interrupt the thread after the time limit and in your thread you have to check for the interruption. Say, in your `while` loop you will check for interruption as `if(isInterrupted()) throw new InterruptedException()` and catch that `Exception` in the `run` method by wrapping everything in `try catch`. Or else if you can wait for the thread only for some time use `join(milliseconds to wait)` method but that does not stop your thread from execution. You can search on stack overflow for interrupting the thread.